# Convert css matrix value for scale to css transform scale(x,y) with JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is the calculation to convert css matrix scale values to 
    transform: scale() values.

As an example I have:

```
var ma = matrix(0.300985, 0.676024, -0.676024, 0.300985, 0, 0);

ma[0];
ma[3];
```

So I need to convert these values for:

```
transform: scale(x,y);
```